# How to debug angular project template

Tags: visual-studio-code

Starting with a new project template

```
dotnet new angular my-app-name
```

This creates a new .net core web app w/angular.
I can debug the sample api controller with the .net core launch profile selected, but how can I debug the typescript code?  I want to step from the angular/ts code into the .net api controller, if possible.

One way I suppose is to simply use Chrome dev tools to debug the Angular/TS code and let it invoke breakpoints in the .net core api, and from there debug in vs code?

Answer (score 0):

Just write **debugger;** where you want to debug in **ts** file and in chrome, keep console window open then reload the project. It will hit where you had written the debugger.

Hope this will help.

Comment: exactly what do you mean by "just write debugger"? you mean print out statement?

Comment: No! In Type Script, just type debugger; where you want to hit the debugging point and keep your chrome's console window open.